# Reuse When condition in result query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, case

I did this query and it works but it is possible to do something more efficient and readable ? I just want to have a result in a query (I don't want to use pl/sql for this). The best would be to store the when condition in a variable but I don't know if it is possible.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (SELECT min(handling_unit_id) FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment where  
        shipment_id = '1371'
        AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
        and structure_level = 1)  is not null
 THEN (SELECT min(handling_unit_id) FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment where  
        shipment_id = '1371'
        AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
        and structure_level = 1)
 ELSE (SELECT min(handling_unit_id) FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment where  
        shipment_id = '1371'
        AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
        and structure_level > 1)
END HUI FROM dual ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a below query (if you want a single value as in the current example):

```
select handling_unit_id
from ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment
where shipment_id = '1371'
  and ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(
    handling_unit_type_id
  ) like 'SST_N1'
  and structure_level >= 1
order by structure_level asc, handling_unit_id asc
fetch first row only
```

What will it do:

1. It orders the data by `structure_level` in ascending order, so given `structure_level >= 1` will return `structure_level = 1` as a first row if it is present and `structure_level > 1` if it is not.
2. If there are many `handling_unit_id` per structure value, then it will put the least `handling_unit_id` at the first row, which is an equivalent of `min`.

Comment: Yes ! I like very much your solution and it works perfectly... Thank you astentx

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a little more compact using the coalesce function

```
SELECT coalesce(
  (SELECT min(handling_unit_id) FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment where  
    shipment_id = '1371'
    AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
    and structure_level = 1),
  (SELECT min(handling_unit_id) FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment where  
    shipment_id = '1371'
    AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
    and structure_level > 1)
  )
FROM dual ;
```

The coalesce function basically returns the first not null value among its input parameters

Answer (score 0):

You may use query factoring or common-table-expression.

```
with tb as (
    SELECT min(handling_unit_id) min_hu_id
    FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment 
    where shipment_id = '1371' 
      AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
      and structure_level = 1)
)
select coalesce(min_hu_id
  ,(SELECT min(handling_unit_id) 
    FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment 
    where shipment_id = '1371'
      AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
      and structure_level > 1)
from tb 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option. Figure out what is common to all three queries and do it once in a CTE (`WITH` clause). Then query that in respective ways to look for what is different in each case. Then there are various modes of doing the CASE/IF-THEN type logic. Here's one means. It uses a tricky `SIGN` operation in order to group all the >1 structure_level values together.

```
WITH data AS (SELECT SIGN(structure_level-1)+1 structure_level_group,min(handling_unit_id) min_handling_unit_id
                FROM ifsapp.handling_unit_shipment 
               WHERE shipment_id = '1371'
                 AND ifsapp.HANDLING_UNIT_TYPE_API.Get_Handling_Unit_Category_Id(handling_unit_type_id) like 'SST_N1'
               GROUP BY SIGN(structure_level-1)+1)
SELECT NVL(t1.min_handling_unit_id,t2.min_handling_unit_id) hui
  FROM (SELECT MIN(min_handling_unit_id)  min_handling_unit_id
          FROM data
         WHERE structure_level_group = 1) t1,
       (SELECT MIN(min_handling_unit_id) min_handling_unit_id
          FROM data
         WHERE structure_level_group = 2) t2
```